# How can I find documents in mongo that satisfy multiple conditions?

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo database where the documents fall into one of three situations.  Either they

```
1)  Don't have a key named "somevalue"
2)  Have "somevalue" but it is set to null
3)  Have "somevalue" but it is set to a valid value
```

I am trying to find all the documents that match 2) above and delete the "somevalue" attribute from those documents.

For example, here is are some sample documents:

1)

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("58214e9ebeac160006000003"),
  "name" : "Internal Stream"
}
```

2)

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("574382e6891ea20007000002"),
  "name" : "Stream 2"
  "somevalue" : null
}
```

3)

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("574382e6891ea20007000002"),
  "name" : "Stream 2"
  "somevalue" : ObjectId("57b4e24373b9a00006000001")
}
```

In one database, I run the following:
db.getCollection('mycollection').find({somevalue : {$exists: true} }).count()

I get 38 records.  Which tells me that there are 38 documents in this collection that match either 2) and 3) above.

If I run the following:
db.getCollection('mycollection').find({somevalue : null }).count()

I get 1859 records which seems to manage 1) and 2) above.

How can I run a query that matches the documents where the field "somevalue" exists AND "somevalue" is set to null?

It seems to me that null matches when the key does not exist or when the key exists and is set to null.

What I am trying to do is delete all the documents that exists but have no value so that when I am done, the documents in the collection only have the attribute if the attribute has an actual value.

Also I doublechecked my version using db.version()
3.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disambiguate null from missing field by using [`$type`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-for-null-fields/#type-check) operator.

So something like

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').find({somevalue : {$type: "null"} })
```

or

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').find({somevalue : {$type: 10} })
```

For [`removal`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/#db.collection.deleteMany) you can try

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').deleteMany({somevalue : {$type: "null"} })
```

Comment: For db.getCollection('mycollection').find({somevalue : {$type: null} })  I get Error: error: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "argument to $type is not a number or a string",
 "code" : 14,
 "codeName" : "TypeMismatch"
}

Comment: oops try  `db.getCollection('mycollection').find({somevalue : {$type: "null"} })`. More info [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#available-types)

Comment: db.getCollection('mycollection').find({somevalue : {$type: 10} }) does not actually help me because I get zero results.  The actual value is ObjectId("57b4e24373b9a00006000001") which ends up returning 0 results.

Comment: db.getCollection('contents_JI_before_findAndModify').find({"geofenceProfileId" : {$type: "null"} }) returns 0 results as well.

Comment: Works for me in both version 3.2 & 3.6 with your sample documents

Comment: type of 7 matches all 38 documents (ie exists and null as well as exists and has valid value).  Any way to filter the type 7 and something else @veeram?

Comment: Correction, type of 7 matches all the valid data results (ie scenario 3) above.  is there a way to negate that to just get the 31 records that are not valid?  It seems nitpicky but I will have to do this across multiple collections and I started with the smallest one first to keep it simple.

Comment: Wait now that I looked at it type 10 gets me exactly what I need @veeram

Comment: Thanks @veeram!  I marked your response as the answer!